# Revert global packagemanager to npm, Windows 10

Tags: angular

To change the packagemanger from npm to yarn.
I used:

```js
ng set --global packageManager=yarn
```

I need to find the json file that containing this setting on my machin.
I cannot find the folder of global setting/installation of Angular/ Angular-CLI on my machine.
Generally, where could I find them in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can file the angular-cli.json global config file here :

> C:\Users\your_username\.angular-cli.json

And in the file replace :

```
{
  "packageManager": "yarn"
}
```

by

```
{
  "packageManager": "npm"
}
```